# Sql Sum specific times

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a varchar type column in my sql table, and am collecting the Working hours from that...
If I give workig hours like

```
WorkingHours
------------
     1
     5
     8
```

I can find the sum of this WorkingHours column value like `Sum(WorkingHours)`, but here I need to give more specific timings like

```
WorkingHours
------------
    01:30
      2
    01:15
    04:45
```

like this, is it possible to sum these values, I tried the same way, but I couldn't come up with any solution, can anyone help me here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you store times as varchar? Use time or datetime of course...

Note that "2", if convertable, would be 48 hours or 2 days. If you don't want to fix your data or datatypes, then you'll have to workaround this

```
DECLARE @feckedTable TABLE (WorkingHours varchar(5));

INSERT @feckedTable (WorkingHours) VALUES ('01:30'), ('02:00'), ('01:15'), ('04:45');

SELECT
    SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CAST(WorkingHours AS smalldatetime))) AS TotalTime
FROM
    @feckedTable

SELECT
    CAST(TotalTime/60 AS varchar(4)) + ':' + CAST(TotalTime % 60 AS char(2))
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, 0, CAST(WorkingHours AS smalldatetime))) AS TotalTime
    FROM
        @feckedTable
    ) X
```

Comment: thanks for ur response gbn, am getting error like "Operand data type smalldatetime is invalid for sum operator."

Comment: how can we sum if the values are like "2","02:30","01:20"

Comment: @Shanish: don't use "2". it's uselsss

Answer (score 1):

select cast(dateadd(millisecond,sum(datediff(millisecond,0,cast(totalhrs as datetime))),0) as time) from table

This is the syntax for getting accuracy upto milliseconds.

Refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793531/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-multiple-datetime-values) for detailed explaination.

Comment: thanks for ur response, am getting error like "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: I have updated the answer with a similar question asked on StackOverflow before.

Comment: What is start time and end time here?