# Cumulative sum function in hive

Tags: sql, hive

Is there any way to get the cumulative count(customer_id) for today's date and a number of days leading up to today's date, i am running count in Hive? The date column in this format:

```
20120907
```

I have 2 columns in my dataset, customer_id and date.

There are also partitions in my table and some of the values in the customer_id column are NULL. I am not sure if there are duplicates so I will use

```
count(distinct(customer_id))
```

Here is an example of my data.

```
 customer_id  date
10001         20140901
10003         20141001
NULL          20150101
10007         20150102
```

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: What do you mean to take the cumulative sum of a date column?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the sum of multiple datetime values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793531/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-multiple-datetime-values)

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, getting the cumulative count of distinct users per day.
The difficulty here is that you hardly can pre-aggregate the counts per day and sum them up, because the days might have "overlapping" users, thus you would count them multiple times instead of once.

But I was stumbling upon [this](https://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/12/11/using-sketch_set-for-reach-estimation/) approach, which basically hashes all users in a "sketch_set" per day and later unions the different hash set, upon which it applies a count estimation.