# SQL SERVER : Sum of multiple datetime rows in HH:MM;SS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add multiple record of datetime in order to get a "Total Time".

How can I achieve that ?

```
2000-01-01 00:01:50.000
2000-01-01 00:02:05.000
2000-01-01 00:03:58.000
2000-01-01 00:04:54.000
```

Total should be : **00:12:57**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793531/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-multiple-datetime-values

Comment: @JimmyFL . . . There is, no doubt, a duplicate to the question.  But one that returns a string does not seem appropriate.

Comment: What should happen if I add `2018-07-18 16:02:23.000` to the mix? Is the `2000-01-01` a constant that's used because someone didn't know the `TIME` data type exists? And what do you want the result to be if the total exceeds 24 hours?

Comment: @JeroenMostert 2000-01-01 is a Constant, that database has been created by the previous developper, and I'm kinda forced to use it as it is

Comment: so you are using 2000-01-01 as a base time?  You can work out the difference between your times and the base date usinf DATEDIFF and SUM them all - but I'm guessing you might want an answer 25:05:45 for example - the versions of SQL I've used don't have that format, but seconds could be made into something like it.  On the other hand, you could sum all the seconds differences, then add them to the 'base date constant you mentioned' it would all be consistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEADD(second,
               SUM(DATEDIFF(second,'20000101', YourIimes)),
               '20000101') 
                        AS TotalTime From YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
select dateadd(ss, sum(datediff(ss, 0, cast(dt as time))), 0) as totaltime
from table t;
```

Comment: [A post I think you'll enjoy](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)

Answer (score 0):

here is a test table with the data to evaluate the logic

```
DECLARE @Records  table (Duration  datetime)
INSERT INTO @Records 
SELECT  '2000-01-01 00:01:50.000'   UNION ALL 
SELECT  '2000-01-01 00:02:05.000'   UNION ALL 
SELECT  '2000-01-01 00:03:58.000'   UNION ALL 
SELECT  '2000-01-01 00:04:54.000'  

SELECT 
    [Total Time]=convert(varchar(10), dateadd(second, SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,'20000101', Duration)), 0), 108)
FROM    
    @Records
```