# Sum Time (hh:mm) in MS Access Using SQL

Tags: ms-access-2016

Good Evening Everyone,

First, thank you to everyone who has taken the time to answer my questions.  Your help has been amazing!!!

I have run into another issue to which I cannot find an answer.  I need to sum the total hours that employees work in hh:mm.  For the sake of clarity, I need to have a result that is not a decimal, but an exact sum expressed in hh:mm such as 3:43.  Below is the table and query that I am using.

How do I get Access to return the needed format?  Can someone point me in the correct direction, please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793531/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-multiple-datetime-values

Comment: did you figure this out?