# Calculate time difference in days:hours:min:sec format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query: Wherein I have to calculate the time difference in Days:Hours:min:sec format

```
Declare @t table (ID int, starttime datetime,EndTime Datetime)

Insert into @t values (1,'2019-11-16 09:39:04.000','2019-11-16 13:43:40.000')
Insert into @t values (1,'2019-11-16 16:49:42.000','2019-11-18 18:02:58.000')

select convert(varchar(550),DateDiff(day, starttime, EndTime)%3600)+'D : '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s, starttime, EndTime)/3600%24)+'H : '+convert(varchar(5),DateDiff     (s,starttime, EndTime)%3600/60)+'M : '+convert(varchar(5),(DateDiff(s, starttime, EndTime)%60)) +'S'   as Duration 
from @t
```

Output:

```
Duration
0D : 4H : 4M : 36S  
2D : 1H : 13M : 16S
```

My question is, how to calculate the sum of the 2 rows?

My desired output is:

```
Duration  
2D : 5H : 17M : 52S
```

Comment: Not storing the data in the format you've given would be a start. Personally I would suggest storing values like these as a duration in the smallest denominator you need; in this case seconds. Then you can easily add them together. Only worry about the value format when you get to the presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu I tried what you said with the help of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793531/how-can-i-get-the-sum-of-multiple-datetime-values but it produces the wrong results

Comment: You could write a laborious function to parse the string and multiply its components by appropriate seconds value.  Your DateDiff(day, starttime, EndTime)%3600)+'D : ' looks wrong - if the difference in dates is 10 years, it's , going to chop 3600 days off for no apparent good reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the difference in second & do aggregation :

```
declare @seconds int

select @seconds = sum(datediff(second, starttime, EndTime))
from @t

select convert(varchar(255), (@seconds / 86400)) + 'D:' +
       convert(varchar(255), ((@seconds % 86400) /3600)) + 'H:'+
       convert(varchar(255), (((@seconds % 86400) % 3600) / 60)) + 'M:'+
       convert(varchar(255), (((@seconds % 86400) % 3600) % 60)) + 'S' as Duration
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could aggregate and then work out the values:

```
WITH Sums AS(
    SELECT ID,
           SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, starttime, EndTime)) Diff
    FROM @t
    GROUP BY ID) --Assumed GROUP BY
SELECT *,
       Diff%60 AS Seconds,
       Diff / 60 % 60 AS [Minutes],
       Diff / 60 / 60 % 24 AS Hours,
       Diff / 60 / 60 /  24 AS Days
FROM Sums;
```

I've put this into separate columns instead, as it's likely easier to consume for a presentation layer